# Find number of Records written by writeStream operation: SparkListener OnTaskEnd always return 0 in Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I want to get the number of records written by writeStream operation.
For that I have this code.

```scala
spark.sparkContext.addSparkListener(new SparkListener() {
  override def onTaskEnd(taskEnd: SparkListenerTaskEnd) {
    val metrics = taskEnd.taskMetrics
    if(metrics.inputMetrics != None){
      inputRecords += metrics.inputMetrics.recordsRead
    }
    if(metrics.outputMetrics != None) {
      println("OUTPUTMETRICIS NOT NONE")
      recordsWritten += metrics.outputMetrics.recordsWritten
      bytesWritten += metrics.outputMetrics.bytesWritten
    }
    numTasks += 1
    println("recordsWritten = " + recordsWritten)
    println("bytesWritten = " + bytesWritten)
    println("numTasks = " + numTasks)
  }
})
```

The code goes into the blocks but the values recordsWritten byteswritten inputrecords are always 0.

**EDIT: Upgraded to 2.3.1 as there was a fix. Still gives 0**

```
Streaming query made progress: {
  "id" : "9c345af0-042c-4eeb-80db-828c5f69e442",
  "runId" : "d309f7cf-624a-42e5-bb54-dfb4fa939228",
  "name" : "WriteToSource",
  "timestamp" : "2018-07-30T14:20:33.486Z",
  "batchId" : 3,
  "numInputRows" : 3511,
  "inputRowsPerSecond" : 2113.786875376279,
  "processedRowsPerSecond" : 3013.733905579399,
  "durationMs" : {
    "addBatch" : 1044,
    "getBatch" : 29,
    "getOffset" : 23,
    "queryPlanning" : 25,
    "triggerExecution" : 1165,
    "walCommit" : 44
  },
  "stateOperators" : [ ],
  "sources" : [ {
    "description" : "KafkaSource[Subscribe[proto2-events-identification-carrier]]",
    "startOffset" : {
      "proto2-events-identification-carrier" : {
        "2" : 22400403,
        "1" : 22313194,
        "0" : 22381260
      }
    },
    "endOffset" : {
      "proto2-events-identification-carrier" : {
        "2" : 22403914,
        "1" : 22313194,
        "0" : 22381260
      }
    },
    "numInputRows" : 3511,
    "inputRowsPerSecond" : 2113.786875376279,
    "processedRowsPerSecond" : 3013.733905579399
  } ],
  "sink" : {
    "description" : "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ConsoleSinkProvider@1350f304"
  }
}
```

Shows this but I cant get it in code.

Comment: -I am also facing the same issue in 2.4.4, In the case of streaming metrics - written and read records are 0 in SparkListner applied on spark.streamcontext(). Please let me know any luck with it.

Answer (score 1):

There [was a bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23288) in FileStreamSink of spark structured streaming that was fixed in version 2.3.1.

As a workaround you can use [accumulators](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#accumulators) just before writing data into a sink.

Comment: I upgraded to 2.3.1 and it still gives 0. 
How to use accumulators is this case. From th examples i understan that have to the counting yourself. But I don't know the count of the records anywhere? how would i aggregate it?

Comment: The issue was fixed in a file sink but it looks like you are using console sink (maybe the same bug is there too). Did you try write in a file?

Comment: I tried file sink to its still not working. Wrote to HDFS/hive same result 0. Any idea?

Comment: Did you try to use SparkListener.onTaskEnd() to capture events and then get metrics from `taskEnd.taskMetrics().outputMetrics().recordsWritten()` or from accumulables `taskEnd.taskInfo().accumulables()`?

Comment: I tried the taskEnd.taskMetrics().outputMetrics().recordsWritten().
Same as above code. 
Just a quick peek at the accumulable API there's no such metric for records.
Do you have any example?

Comment: @YuriyBondaruk - I am using spark 2.4.4 and even checked in a lower.2.4.0 and upgraded version 2.4.7 of spark with scala 2.11. taskEnd.taskMetrics().outputMetrics().recordsWritten() and read records are 0.

Answer (score 0):

Spark structured streaming has a dedicated listener location for query progress in the **StreamingQueryManager**:

```
 spark.streams.addListener(new StreamingQueryListener {
    override def onQueryStarted(event: StreamingQueryListener.QueryStartedEvent): Unit = {
      //code
    }

    override def onQueryProgress(event: StreamingQueryListener.QueryProgressEvent): Unit = {
      println("Total number of records written to the sink: "+event.progress.sink.numOutputRows)
    }

    override def onQueryTerminated(event: StreamingQueryListener.QueryTerminatedEvent): Unit = {
      //code
    }
})
```